# set a random color in draw method

Tags: java, random, colors

Ok so this is a shape drawn with a random color, however I'd like that shape to stay that color while being repainted. Right now with this draw method it just draws a new random color every `repaint()` so it looks like a rainbow shape. How would I make it grab a random color then stick with that for that particular shape?

```
public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(new Color(randomNum.nextInt(256), randomNum.nextInt(256), randomNum.nextInt(256)));
    g.fillOval((int)getX(),(int)getY(), getRadius(), getRadius());

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By saving the color you're drawing.
So you'll only randomly generate it once, and then keep using that color to redraw each time.

Either generate it before the draw like `Color c = new Color(randomNum.nextInt(256), randomNum.nextInt(256), randomNum.nextInt(256));` or only generate the variable and test if it has been initialized in your draw method. If it hasn't (the first time running your code), you generate a random color, if it has been initialized, you just skip generating the color and go straight to your `g.fillOval`

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, I generated the variables before draw and it worked.

Comment: Glad to help :) Now you're clearly not new around here, so I don't want to be a pain in the ass about it, but would you mind accepting the answer seeing as you said it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You keep a list of shapes. every shape has his color and radius.

when repaint, you draw every shape in the list.

```
static class OvalShape {Color color; int radius;}
List<OvalShape> shapeList = new ArrayList<>();

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    for(Shape s : shapeList) {
        g.setColor(s.color);
        g.fillOval((int)getX(),(int)getY(), s.radius, s.radius);
    }
}
```